# Логика использования interface в C#

Tags: c#

Добрый всем день.

Задача разобраться с интерфейсами. У меня есть интерфейс

```
interface ICheturehugolMain
{
    int x { get; set; }
    int y { get; set; }
    int width { get; set; }
    int hight { get; set; }
    void Draw(Graphics g);
}
```

А также 3 класса, унаследованные от этого интерфейса, допустим, один из них

```
class CheturehugolVrashatelnoe : ICheturehugolMain
{

    public int x { get; set; }

    public int y { get; set; }

    public int width { get; set; }

    public int hight { get; set; }

    public CheturehugolVrashatelnoe()
    {
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
    }
}
```

Итак, мы  использовали интерфейс, но я никак не могу понять, где логика его использования, получается, создали шаблон (интерфейс) (метода и 4-х свойств) и в 3-х классах их реализовали по своему, с таким же успехом можно было просто создать 3 класса и никакого интерфейса не делать, или же создать абстрактный класс и переопределить, где необходимо, методы в классах наследника (так понятно зачем и почему), но все-таки хочется узнать, как правильно реализовать в данной задаче интерфейс, чтоб он нес какой-то смысл в коде.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Интерфейс как раз и нужен, чтобы создать определенный "шаблон", который обязывает классы наследники предоставлять определенные методы. Для примера, если взять интерфейс "автомобиль", а в нем метод "запустить двигатель", то из этого следует, что для любого автомобиля можно "запустить двигатель". А как это будет сделано, зависит от конкретной реализации: кнопочку нажать, как на спорткаре, ключ повернуть, как на большинстве, или толкать с мужиками, как на старом москвиченке.
Абстрактный класс не выход, так как в С# нет множественного наследования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать и абстрактный класс, но основное отличие между классами и интерфейсами в том, что интерфейсов класс может реализовывать сколько угодно, а базовый класс у него всегда один.

Comment: В данной задаче, когда у нас один интерфейс, лучше сделать все-таки абстрактный класс, (или как можно разбросать 4 свойства и один метод по разным интерфейсам, (ну чтобы все-таки использовать интерфейсы)), а если у нас было бы много интерфейсов, то тут без них обойтись никак получается (из-за возможности реализации).

Comment: Да, и кстати абстрактный класс создают, когда есть конкретная или общая логика для потомков. а если просто создать абстрактный класс с абстрактными методами, то тогда лучше интерфейс.

Answer (score 0):

Главное отличие класса от интерфейса — в том, что класс состоит из интерфейса и реализации.

Любой класс всегда неявно объявляет свой интерфейс — то, что доступно при использовании класса извне. У Вас есть интерфейс ICheturehugolMain описывающий поведение объектов.

Предположим что у вас метод, который отрисовывает объекты. Тогда его можно объявить так:

```
void DrawCheturehugol(ICheturehugolMain figure)
{
   figure.Draw();
   ...
}
```

или так:

```
void DrawCheturehugols(IEnumerable<ICheturehugolMain> figures)
{
   foreach (ICheturehugolMain figure in figures)
   {
      figure.Draw();
      ...
   }
}
```

Что это нам дает?

1. У всех фигур может быть своя реализация метода Draw.
2. Код не зависит от конкретных классов. Он зависит от интерфейсов
3. Можно объединять данные фигуры в коллекции. Например:

> List, ICheturehugolMain[] и т.д.